# operator[] overload to accept char * for subscript

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have following code:

```
class IList{
public:
    virtual const Pair *get(const char *key) const = 0;

    inline const Pair *operator[](const char *key) const;
};

inline const Pair *IROList::operator[](const char *key) const{
    return get(key);
}
```

code compiles ok, but when I try to use it:

```
IList *list = (IList *) SomeFactory();
Pair *p;
p = list["3 city"];
```

I got:

```
test_list.cc:47:19: error: invalid types ‘IList*[const char [7]]’ for array subscript
  p = list["3 city"];
                   ^
```

I can understand that array subscript is int or char,
but then how std::map is doing char* / strings ?

Comment: What is the type of `list`?

Comment: exactly. list is a pointer to class

Comment: @Nick And you're attempting to subscript the pointer, not to call your operator overload.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `list` is a pointer as well you can't use `[]` operator in the way you did. That's because `list["3 city"]` is equivalent to `list.operator[]("3 city")`. If you provide pointer, you'd have to use `list->operator[]("3 city")` or - what is more readable - `(*list)["3 city"]`. Of course, you can also make your list a reference and use normally:

```
auto& listRef = *list;
p = listRef["3 city"];
```

Comment: this is why everyone these days using & instead of *

Comment: and because * in c++ is usually bad and ugly;)

Comment: well I did no C++ for 5-6 years and now I found C++ is like bad Java. This is more like new question, but does people do `Book *b = new Book();` or `Book &rb = *new Book();` If I do second, I must `delete &rb;` ?

Comment: @Nick Actually, your example is correct, however I haven't seen such a form so far (I don't see a point in doing so). There is C++14 available nowadays and if you must use a pointer, you use [smart pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) e.g. `auto b = std::make_unique();` and you don't care about doing `delete` anymore:) If you need a reference from the pointer, you just dereference it `Book& b = *bookPointer;`.

Comment: I know about smart pointers, yesterday I just upgrade the project from C++ to C++11 :) Will keep manual delete for the moment, but will change pointers to refs.

Answer (score 3):

It seems list is a pointer to IList object. So you should try:
p = (*list)["3 city"];